# Tutorials and Samples for Host Integration Server

Tags: .net, integration, host

I am fairly new in the Cross over Integration world of enterprise applications like MS and IBM systems. I need to know if anyone can **redirect me to any website or links** that shows some samples of communication with Mainframe servers using .NET applications via Host Integration server.

I will be very thankful.

Thanks

Mohit B.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Go through these links:

1. http://assets1.csc.com/in/downloads/Microsoft_Integration_Technologies_For_Application_Integration.pdf
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163294.aspx?ppud=4
3. http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/dotnet/archives/0107/raiford/index.html